# Counterbalancing in open sesame

Tags: python-2.7, open-sesame

I a writing an inline_script in open sesame (python).
Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? (i think its something very simple, but i can not find it)

## when i put the number in List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] the first line works, but the second does not work :(

```
BalanceList1 = range(1:7) + range(13:19) #does not work 
if self.get('subject_nr') == "BalanceList1": 

#here follows a list of commands

BalanceList2 = list(range(7:13))+list(range(19:25)) #does not work either
elif self.get('subject_nr') == "BalanceList2":

#other commands
```

Comment: `BalanceList1 = range(1:6) + range(13:19)` will do what you want.

Comment: I still get "invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2.x you can do the following:

```
BalanceList1 = range(1,6) + range(13,19)
```

which will generate 2 lists and add them together in `BalanceList1`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

In python 3.x, `range` doesn't return a `list` anymore but an iterator (and `xrange` is gone), you have to explicitly convert to `list`:

```
BalanceList1 = list(range(1,6))+list(range(13,19))
```

A more optimal way to avoid creating too many temporary lists would be:

```
BalanceList1 = list(range(1,6))
BalanceList1.extend(range(13,19))  # avoids creating the list for 13->18
```

more optimal than: